# Missing $ error in math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, cases

I have the following LaTeX code (beginning from line 80):

```
\begin{definition}
$\hat{n}_{v}$ = \begin{cases}
$n_{v}$ & \text{ if } $v \in$ \text{connected component of size} $< \frac{2}{\epsilon}$
 \\
$\frac{2}{\epsilon}$ & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}

\end{definition}
```

However, when I want to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
./lect42.tex:80: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.80 $\hat{n}_{v}$ = \begin{cases}
```

I looked at the code carefully, but there are no missing $'s. Why I get this error?

Comment: The `cases` environment is defined only for math mode AFAIK, as part of the `amsmath` bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have lots of unnecessary dollar symbols, and one missing from the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\hat{n}_{v} = \begin{cases}
n_{v} & \text{ if } v \in \text{connected component of size} < \frac{2}{\epsilon}
 \\
\frac{2}{\epsilon} & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$
\end{document}
```

As this is quite a large expression, I would be inclined to use `\[` and `\]` instead of the dollar signs, to create a displayed equation, rather than an in-text equation. You could also use `\displaystyle` to enlarge the fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\hat{n}_{v} = \begin{cases}
n_{v} & \text{ if } v \in \text{connected component of size} < \displaystyle\frac{2}{\epsilon} \\
\displaystyle\frac{2}{\epsilon} & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked like a charm! i thought i was being cautious by putting those $'s everywhere..

Comment: I'd use `dfrac` instead of `\displaystyle\frac`

Comment: @cmhughes In that case it doesn't matter much, because the fractions are the last thing in the cell; but yes, in general `\dfrac` would be better.